Blazor - Blazorex Error - Client.dll missing
I have the default Blazor WebApp. .NET9, Auto Rendering with Global.
I've added the nuget package for Blazorex to the client side.
When I build I get the error:

Metadata file

'C:\xxxx\xxxx\source\repos\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx.Client\obj\Debug\net9.0\ref\xxxxx.Client.dll'
could not be found

I've included:
@using Blazorex

In the client _Imports.razor file
Code on the razor page is as follows:
@page "/Blazorex"
@using global::Blazorex

<Canvas Width="800" Height="600" 
        OnFrameReady="(t) => OnFrameReady(t)"
        OnCanvasReady="(ctx) => OnCanvasReady(ctx)" />

@code {
    CanvasBase _canvas;

    private void OnCanvasReady(CanvasBase canvas)
    {
        _canvas = canvas;
    }

    private void OnFrameReady(float timeStamp)
    {
        // your render logic goes here
    }
}

Naturally tried restarting everything.
If I remove all traces of Blazorex it runs fine.
Does anybody know why I get the .dll missing error?
